# Установка драйвера MySQL для Qt 5.12.2 Windows

Tags: mysql, qt5, windows-10

Имеется Qt 5.12.2 на Win10(1903)x64. нужно поставить драйвер для MySQL.
при этом в директории нужного мне компилятора творится вот такая вот ситуация.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я предполагаю, что драйвер нужно собрать и поставил mysql 8.0 как этого требует оф. инструкция, но при попытке qmake мне в ответ вываливается сообщение

```
D:\Qt\5.12.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake "INCLUDEPATH += C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" "LIBS+= C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\libmysql.lib" mysql.pro
Cannot read D:/Qt/5.12.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/qtsqldrivers-config.pri: No such file or directory
Project ERROR: Library 'mysql' is not defined.

D:\Qt\5.12.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR=C:/MySQL/include "MYSQL_LIBDIR=C:/MYSQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib/opt"
Cannot read D:/Qt/5.12.2/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/qtsqldrivers-config.pri: No such file or directory 
Project ERROR: Library 'mysql' is not defined.
```

Как с этим бороться и как заставить MySQL работать в проектах?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первая ваша ошибка заключается в том, что вы команду запускаете не в той директории.

Исправьте вот это
 D:\Qt\5.12.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR=C:/MySQL/include "MYSQL_LIBDIR=C:/MYSQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib/opt"
на вот это
D:\Qt\5.12.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR=C:/MySQL/include "MYSQL_LIBDIR=C:/MYSQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib/opt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим, у меня база данных **MySQL** установлена в директорию **D:/mysql**, а **Qt** в директории **D:\Qt**

1. Запустите консоль с настроенным окружением для Qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Смените директорию на **D:\Qt\Qt5.11.2\5.11.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Выполните команду **qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR=D:/mysql/include "MYSQL_LIBDIR=D:/mysql/lib"**
4. Выполните команду **mingw32-make**
5. Результат компиляции (новые драйвера) можно найти в директории **D:\Qt\Qt5.11.2\5.11.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\plugins\sqldrivers**
6. Скопируйте новые драйвера в папку **D:\Qt\Qt5.11.2\5.11.2\mingw53_32\plugins\sqldrivers**
7. Скопируйте файлы **libmysql.dll** и **libmysqld.dll** из директории **D:\mysql\lib** в директорию **D:\Qt\Qt5.11.2\5.11.2\mingw53_32\bin**

После проделанной работы, можете запускать свои проекты, которые используют соединение с базой данных MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо.
Заработало.
Фраза "с настроенным окружением для Qt" должна быть понята так: в QT Creator посмотреть, где реально расположен компилятор g++.exe (Инструменты - Параметры - Комплекты - Компиляторы - поле внизу - Путь к компилятору) - именно этот путь нужно прописать в path (я разместил его в системных).
mysql взял здесь https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/?version=5.6.23 - вторая кнопка - мне нужна было старенькая версия.

Comment: Извините, но в вопросе нет такой фразы: _Фраза "с настроенным окружением для Qt"_. Это ответ или комментарий к ранее данному ответу?