# PyQt5: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, windows, pyqt5

Никак не могу подружить базу ***MySql*** с ***PyQt5***.

Скрипт:

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
 

def openDatabase():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
    db.setDatabaseName("nir")
    db.setHostName("localhost")
    db.setPassword("root")
    db.setUserName("root")
    return db
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 
    db = openDatabase()
    db.open()
    print(db.lastError().text())
```

Output:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMARIADB QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
```

Система: **Windows** 10 64x, ***Python*** 3.8.5, ***PyQt5*** v5.15.1

Как советуют в гугле, скачал отдельно Qt (в т.ч. MinGW-8.1.0 64-bit), собрал по инструкции
[отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1007223/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-mysql-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-qt-5-12-2-windows) драйвер qsqlmysql.dll, закинул в папку C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\sqldrivers

В папку с проектом положил файлы libmysql.dll, libmysql.lib, mysqlclient.lib из C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib

В PATH прописал:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\sqldrivers

И после всех этих манипуляций, pyqt5 все еще не может загрузить драйвер.

Answer (score 0):

Вот нашел для вас следующий вариант
решения проблемы подключения ***PyQt5*** к базе данных **MySQL**. **`Драйвер не загружен`**

Решение под ***Windows***:

1. Найдите динамическую библиотеку ***MySQL*** по следующему пути:
   `libmysql.dll` (конкретный путь определяется местом установки MySQL на вашем компьютере)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Затем скопируйте файл по пути `path/Qt/bin` в пакете `PyQt5`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверьте и напишите пожалуйста что у вас получилось.

Comment: Добавил, к сожалению, ничего не изменилось

Comment: @hehelf  попробуйте почитать пост https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64056483/unable-to-load-qmysql-driver-on-pyside2