В QTableView не отображаются данные из таблицы базы MySQL
Данные из таблицы читаю, в таблицу пишу. 
Qt Designer 5.11, Python 3.12.
Буду благодарен за подсказку!
    from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
    from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
    from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
    from mysql.connector import connect, Error
    import pymysql
    import pymysql.cursors
    from test_nt import Ui_MainTestNT


    class nntt (QMainWindow):
        def __init__ (self):
            super(nntt, self).__init__()

            self.ui = Ui_MainTestNT()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            self.view_data()

        # Соединение с БД
        try:
            connection = pymysql.connect(
                host="localhost",
                port=3306,
                user="hd_main",
                password="********",        
                database="hdoh_db",
                cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
            )
            # Проверка соединения с БД
            print ("OK")

        except Error as e:
            print(e)

        # Отображение исходных данных
        def view_data(self):
            self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
            self.model.setTable("new_table")
            self.model.select()
            self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = nntt()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())


Нужно использовать QSqlDatabase для соединения с бд

Попробуй добавить еще одну строку в конце self.ui.tableView.show() как в указано в документации https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtSql/QSqlTableModel.html



Нужно использовать QSqlDatabase для соединения с бд... Тут полезло другое, "QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded". Вот таким 'print(QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers())' получил список драйверов и в списке нет QMYSQL. Полез в проблему и понял что как-то все сложно по подключению этого драйвера руками. Пока ступор





Попробуй добавить еще одну строку в конце self.ui.tableView.show()  --> не помогло



YevhenMT, Попробуйте проверить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181326

Код тот же самый, только база SQLite, - все работает/ db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')         db.setDatabaseName('hdoh_db.db'). Чудеса

@S. Nick, спасибо, я это читал, не помогает

YevhenMT,   давно это было, но просто проверьте как вариант https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159238/visualizar-tabla-de-postgresql-con-pyqt5/160098#160098

У вас же не заданы настройки для подключения к серверу MySQL.
В блоке try - except вы проверяете соединение с сервером с помощью pymysql.connect, при этом у блока отступы неверные - он не запускается в init (при создании объекта).
И вам необходимо использовать QSqlDatabase для подключения к базе.
Например так:
 con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL/MARIADB")
 con.setDatabaseName(name)
 con.setHostName(host)
 con.setUserName(username)
 con.setPassword(password)  # хотя этот вариант небезопасный

Доступно описано здесь https://is20-2019.susu.ru/utkinaea/2021/03/15/obrabotka-baz-dannyh-sql-s-pomoshhyu-pyqt-osnovy/#id16
